# ember data extract single serializer

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, serialization

I have an object "Residence" and a residence has many details. When data is returned from the server, how do I use the serializer "extractSingle" to map its relationship? I have the following and I am getting the error "Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference". Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
App.Residence = DS.Model.extend({
residence_ID: attr('number'),
house_Number: attr('string'),
street: attr('string'),
city_ID: attr('number'),
state_ID: attr('number'),
zip: attr('string'),
apt: attr('string'),
client_ID: attr('number'),
client: null,
lead: null,
projectDetails: DS.hasMany('projectDetail')
});


App.ResidenceSerializer = DS.WebAPISerializer.extend({
primaryKey: 'residence_ID',

extractSingle: function (store, primaryType, payload) {
    var primaryTypeName = primaryType.typeKey;

    var typeName = primaryTypeName,
        type = store.modelFor(typeName);

    var data = {};
    data[typeName] = payload;
    data.projectDetails = [];

    var normalizedArray = payload.projectDetails.map(function (nav) {
        data.projectDetails.push(nav);
    }, this);
    payload.projectDetails = payload.projectDetails.mapProperty('projectDetailID');

    payload = data;
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
},

normalizeHash: {
    projectDetails: function (hash) {
        hash.residence_ID = hash.id;
        hash.id = hash.projectDetailID;
        return hash;
    },
    residence: function (hash) {
        hash.residence_ID = hash.id;
        return hash;
    }
}

});
```

and here is the JSON returned from server

```
   {
   "residence_ID":3532,
   "house_Number":"243",
   "street":"Main St.",
   "city_ID":2,
   "state_ID":33,
   "zip":"11111",
   "apt":"35",
   "client_ID":3598,
   "projectDetails":[{"projectDetailID":4947,"residence_ID":3532"},   {"projectDetailID":4947,"residence_ID":3532}]
   }
```

Comment: Can you show how your json is coming down?

Comment: I just posted the json. Don't know why I can't put it in the code section

Answer (score 1):

```
return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
```

your throwing away all of your work at the end and returning the super implementation.  You could just `return data;`.

As a side note the reference in `arguments` doesn't get updated when you set `payload = data;`

Comment: I did what you suggested but still getting the same error. I exacted the code and put it in a separate file DS.WebAPISerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend and this does not give me error and returns the correct number of records. I don't really understand why, this file was created by ember template and is a generic for all exact single models, for testing I added code to make children for this particular model. I however can't seem to get the value by doing get.()